# What is the best way to farm Monkey King's Garb (Sunwuko Set)

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I have been playing a Monk for around 50 hours now and I haven't got a single drop of this item. I am now just planning to farm it as best as I can but am unsure how to do this.

What is the best way to achieve this set? Shall I do GR? Or normal rifts on T1 over and over until I get them?

Or is aiming for blood shards better as I have read you can get this set in there. Any help would be great as I feel like im wasting a lot of time by farming the wrong places for these items.

All my gear is pretty weak, I have a DH that has 900k damage so I can run T3 and handle it pretty well. Thats what I have been using to farm T1 rifts for blood shards.

Comment: Since you can't choose your drops just do whatever you can to maximize how many legendaries you can find in as short a time possible. This set in particular doesn't have many pieces I would suggest blood shards as you can choose which slot you're trying to get a piece for, even more useful when you already have a couple pieces.

Comment: The higher the Torment level the better the chance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to get legendaries but so far the fastest way I've found are...

### Farming

Pick the higher Torment difficulty (important since Monkey King's Garb is a Torment-only drop) in which you can kill the mob really fast (elite pack should take less than 10 sec). Then go rifting. Nephalem rifts have a 100% buff on legendary drop chance compared to the rest of the game so if you're going to drop the set it's in a Nephalem Rift. Plus when you kill the Guardian you get some bloodshard which leads to...

### Gambling

Slot by Slot, you'll have to spend your bloodshard at Kadala. This is especially usefull when you will own several piece of the set and only a few will be missing. You'll be assured that if you get a legendary at Kadala it's for the gear slot you are targetting and not something else. However it takes time and dedication since Kadala is not the most cooperative NPC in the game :).

So when luck on drop is not on your side you can try...

### Sharing

When I was farming the Torment-only set for Demon Hunter, I've found that forming groups of 4 Demon Hunters and farm together was the most efficient. Why ? Because if you drop a piece that you already have you can share it with someone who needs it. Since this works both ways farming with 4 Monks should get you this set way faster. In order to find people to party with you can head to the Blizzard's forums ([European](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/2823159/) or [United States](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/3354998/) depending on your server) and create a topic to find people **or/and** join a Class-specific (Monk in your case) community in game. Open the community menu and you can filter by Class. If I'm not mistaken the biggest Monk Community is called "The Temple" but I'm not a 100% sure. However you should find quite easily.

### Using Kanai's Cube

Since patch 2.3 you can use Kanai's cube to get legendaries faster. If you have enough crafting materials and Horadric Cache materials this is by far the fastest way to gear up for a build. Basically you simply have to :

1) Use the Receipe : **Hope of Cain** to upgrade a level 70 rares items into legendaries until you get the legendary you need. If you need rares items you can either :

- Gamble at Kadala and upgrade the rares she gives you.
- Craft level 70 rare of the desired type.

2) Once you have your desired legendary, use the receipe **Law of Kulle** until you get the desired affixes.

If you need to finish a set, you can also use the receipe **Skill of Nilfur** that allows you to swap an item from a set to another random item from that set. Then use the **Law of Kulle** to get the desired affixes.

Using this method I've been able to fully gear my last Monk in less than a day. Of course I had prior farmed **a lot** of crafting and Horadric Caches materials.

Note that both upgrading a rare and rerolling with the law of Kulle can result in getting an ancient legendary. However this works both way and rerolling an ancient can transform it into a regular legendary

Comment: Very useful, thank you for your answer. Going to the forums is a good idea to create a party of 4, but will people share the gear even if they have it already? I mean there is no reason why they shouldn't but I tend to think that people wouldn't.

Comment: You under-estimate D3 players. Since everything is bound to account, you cannot sell/trade anymore which means duplicate legendaries have no usefull purpose and end up as forgotten soul. So why not give it away when you don't need it. Plus when looking for people you can specify that you look for likely minded players and everything will be fin. I've bee doing that for month now as DH and I give as much stuff as I recieved and everything works fine :D

Comment: I will give it ago then! No harm in trying this, I will mark this answer as correct as I found it most useful!

Answer (score 1):

Most items can drop anywhere, so you should maximize your legendary drop rate. This means playing on as high a difficulty as you can efficiently clear. Personally, I noticed legendaries started dropping more consistently around T4, but that could have just been RNG.

Personally, I did the following to farm set items:

1. Run bounties until you have a lot of rift fragments
2. Run rifts until you get a trials key.
3. Run the trials, and run greater rifts until they get too hard for you.
4. Repeat

When you get close to the blood shards cap of 500, spend shares on whatever slot you are targeting next.

Comment: Probably will not be possibly for OP's characters yet but I seem to consistently get 2-4 legs per run of Grift 28-32, so yes those are a good place to start.

Comment: The problem is my Monk is super weak (around 350k) damage as I do not seem to be getting any good drops at all. If I was to farm on my DH the items would mainly drop as items for DH, it's a little annoying as on my DH I got item sets all the time. Yet on my monk I can't seem to get many at all, anyone on here powerful enough to run me through some T4+ rifts? ;)

Comment: For class specific legendaries, it's also a good idea to use that class; they're weighted to drop for their class more than others, I believe.

Comment: @Ruddy Unfortunately I don't have anything to suggest other than to keep playing, and slowly over time your character should improve. Gambling with blood shards can help a lot, since you can target a specific slot that way.